# Reverse a string each two characters with Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, reverse

I want to reverse a string each two characters with Ruby.

The input:

```
"0123456789abcdef"
```

The output that I expect:

```
"efcdab8967452301"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it:

```
"0123456789abcdef".scan(/../).reverse.join == "efcdab8967452301"
```

Comment: Almost, remove the `('')` :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
"0123456789abcdef".gsub(/../, &:reverse).reverse
# => "efcdab8967452301"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
"0123456789abcdef".chars.each_slice(2).to_a.reverse.join
```

Answer (score 1):

I like all the solutions, especially @sawa's, but now, six hours later, its a challenge to come up with something different.  In the interest of diversity, I offer a way that uses pairwise substitution.  It's destructive, so I start by making a copy of the string.

**Code**

```
str = "0123456789abcdef"
s = str.dup
(0...s.size/2).step(2) { |i| s[i,2], s[-i-2,2] = s[-i-2,2], s[i,2] }
  s #=> "efcdab8967452301"
```

**Explanation**

Letting

```
enum = (0...s.size/2).step(2) #=> #<Enumerator: 0...8:step(2)>
```

we can see what is enumerated:

```
enum.to_a                     #=> [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

The string

```
s #=> "0123456789abcdef"
```

is as follows after each call to the block:

```
i = 0: "ef23456789abcd01" 
i = 2: "efcd456789ab2301" 
i = 4: "efcdab6789452301" 
i = 6: "efcdab8967452301"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"0123456789abcdef".split('').each_slice(2).to_a.reverse.flatten.join('')

=> "efcdab8967452301"
```